# Python dictionary comprehension with sets

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function which returns a set:

- First value of set is the id (dictionary key)
- Second value of set is a list (dictionary value)

I want to create a dict comprehension and use the set to populate the dictionary keys and values. Need assistant getting the value from function and use it to populate the key and value.

Expected result:

```
{ 52: [1, 2, 3, 4], 94: [3, 4, 5, 4]}
```

I have the following code to simplify example: *(You can ignore the enumerate)*

```
from random import randint
a1 = [1,2,3]
b1 = [3,4,5]

l = [a1, b1]

def add_value(a):
    return randint(0,100), a + [4]

d = {x: add_value(y) for x, y in enumerate(l, start=1)}
print d
```

Now d prints:

```
{1: (52, [1, 2, 3, 4]), 2: (94, [3, 4, 5, 4])}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you're using `enumerate`, since you're not working with indices here.

The following would create the dictionary you want using the tuples returned by your function:

```
d = dict(add_value(x) for x in l)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {x:y for x,y in [add_value(li) for li in l]}
```

should work.
In this case, you first create a list of tuples returned by the function add_value, then for each item of this list, you unpack the tuple, and add a key:value to the dictionary.

There must be a better way, but your question is harder than it seems at the first view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this way

```
d = {add_value(y)[0]:add_value(y)[1] for y in [a1,b1]}
```

or

```
d = dict(add_value(y) for y in [a1,b1])
```

Comment: Calling the function twice isn't very neat.